# How do I create a button inside an HTML table to make PHP execute a MySQL database query without needing a seperate js file?

Tags: php, mysql

This is where I wanted to bring in simple onclick event to change a value in db.

```
    echo "<h2>User Accounts</h2>";
    echo "<div style='float: left; width: 40%'>";
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT username, statid, activated, level FROM accesslist ORDER BY level DESC");
    $stmt->execute();
    $results = $stmt->fetchAll();
        echo "<table class=\"table_lines\" cellspacing=0 cellpadding=6 border=0 width=95%>";
            echo "<thead>";
                echo "<th>#</th>";
                echo "<th>Username</th>";
                echo "<th>Status</th>";
                echo "<th>Remove Account</th>";
            echo "</thead>";
            echo "<tbody>";
            if($result['activated'] = 1)
                    {
                        $activation = "Activated";
                        $count = 1;
                        foreach($results as $result)
                            {
                                echo "<tr>";
                                    echo "<td>" . $count . "</td>";
                                    echo "<td><a href='http://www.************.php?id=" . $result['statid'] . "'>" . $result['username'] . "</a></td>";
                                    echo "<td align=\"center\">" . $activation . " <input type=\"submit\" class= \"button\" name= \"deactivate\" value=\"Deactivate\" /></td>";
                                    echo "<td><input type=\"submit\" class= \"button\" name=\"deleteuser\" value=\"Remove Account\" /></td>";
                                echo "</tr>";
                                $count++;
                            }
                    }
                    else
                    { 
                        $activation = "Not Activated";
                        $count = 1;
                        foreach($results as $result)
                            {
                                echo "<tr>";
                                    echo "<td>" . $count . "</td>";
                                    echo "<td><a href='http://www.**********.php?id=" . $result['statid'] . "'>" . $result['username'] . "</a></td>";
                                    echo "<td align=\"center\">" . $activation . " <input type=\"submit\" class= \"button\" name= \"activate\" value=\"Activate\" /></td>";
                                    echo "<td><input type=\"submit\" class= \"button\" name=\"deleteuser\" value=\"Remove Account\" /></td>";
                                echo "</tr>";
                                $count++;
                            }
                    }
        
            echo "</tbody>";
        echo "</table>";
    echo "[END]";
    $dbh = null;
    
}
```

This is how it looks right now:

[image: this is how it looks right now]

I also have 3 functions

```
function activateUser($username)
{
    global $dbh;

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE accesslist SET activated = 1 LIMIT 1");
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
}

function deactivateUser($username)
{
    global $dbh;

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE accesslist SET activated = 0 LIMIT 1");
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
}
function deleteUser($username)
{
    global $dbh;

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("DELETE FROM accesslist WHERE username = $username LIMIT 1");
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

I have tried using "form action='http://**********.php' method='post'";
and if(isset($_POST['activate'])) but the button doesn't seem to when clicked. Probably I was doing something wrong. :/

P.S. I'm a beginner. I have to know if there are simpler ways of onclick inside the php itself to effect change in db without the seperate js EventListener.

Comment: submit it as ulr or form, or use ajax

Comment: If you want the page to stay (what I suppose) you'll need an ajax-call. (just google it...) It's javascript, yes, but it's not a seperate js-file. You will need a dedicated php-script that receives this ajax call and reacts (makes the change in db) accordingly.

Comment: Don't forget `WHERE` clauses for your `UPDATE` statements... I think PDO's bindParam doesn't work like you think it works. Check it out on php.net again.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it with AJAX clearly I will give you some codes I hope it can be help you, this codes be referance for you..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function activate(id) { // you can duplicate this function any way you like
       $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'functions.php',
            data: {
                username: id,
                type:'Active';
                   },
            success: function (answer) {
                $("#result").html(answer) // if you wanna get response from function.php
            }
        })
    }
</script>
```

In Function.php

```
<?PHP

$username = $_POST['username ']; or you can get NAME
$Type = $_POST['type'];

if ($Type='Active') // you can duplicate any way you like
{
    global $dbh;

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE accesslist SET activated = 1 LIMIT 1");
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
}

?>
```

finally change this line

```
 echo "<td><input type=\"submit\" class= \"button\" name=\"deleteuser\" value=\"Remove Account\" /></td>";
```

to

```
 echo "<td><button type=\"button\" class= \"button\" name=\"deleteuser\" OnClick=\"activate('.$result['username'].');\" />Remove Account</button></td>";
```